# Hide website filenames in URL

Tags: url, jsf, facelets, java-ee-6, web.xml

I would like to hide the webpage name in the url and only display either the domain name or parts of it.

For example:

I have a website called "MyWebSite". The url is: localhost:8080/mywebsite/welcome.xhtml. I would like to display only the  "localhost:8080/mywebsite/".

However if the page is at, for example, localhost:8080/mywebsite/restricted/restricted.xhtml then I would like to display localhost:8080/mywebsite/restricted/.

I believe this can be done in the web.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you want URL rewriting.  Check out this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine - there are many approaches to URL rewriting, you need to decide what is appropriate for you.  Some of the approaches do make use of the web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several ways. The one I see most is to have a "front door" called a rewrite engine that parses the URL dynamically to internally redirect the request, without exposing details about how that might happen as you would see if you used simple query strings, etc. This allows the URL you specify to be digested into a request for a master page with specific content, instead of just looking up a physical page at that location to serve.

The StackExchange sites do this so that you can link to a question in a semi-permanent fashion (and thus can use search engines with crawlers that log these URLs) without them having to have a real page in the file system for every question that's ever been asked (we're up to 9,387,788 questions as of this one).